# Why am I being redirected even when component class has no redirect Angular5

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am facing this weird situation.  I have 3 routes in a lazy loaded module.

confirm.route

```
  this.sub =  this._route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        const txn_id = params['id'];
        const transactions = this.store.select(fromStore.getAllTransactions);
         this.store.dispatch(  new actions.Query() );
          transactions.subscribe(data => {
          this.transaction =  data.filter((item) => {
             return item.id === txn_id;
          });
          this.transaction = this.transaction[0];

          if(this.transaction) {
            if(this.transaction.payStatus){
               this._notify.update('This transaction is completed.
 You will be redirected!', 'info');
              setTimeout(() => {
                this._router.navigate([`/success/${this.transaction.id}`]);
              }, 3000);
            }
          }
       });
      });
```

success.route

```
  this.sub =  this._route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      const txn_id = params['id'];
      const transactions = this.store.select(fromStore.getAllTransactions);
       this.store.dispatch(  new actions.Query() );
        transactions.subscribe(data => {
        this.transaction =  data.filter((item) => {
           return item.id === txn_id;
        });
        this.transaction = this.transaction[0];
        if(this.transaction) {
          if(!this.transaction.payStatus){
            this._notify.update('This transaction is not completed.
 You will be redirected!', 'info');
            setTimeout(() => {
              this._router.navigate([`confirm/${this.transaction.id}`]);
            }, 3000);
          } 
        }
     });
    });
```

status.route

```
 onStatusSubmit(){
    const txn_id = this.statusForm.value.txn_id;
      const transactions = this.store.select(fromStore.getAllTransactions);
       this.store.dispatch(  new actions.Query() );
       transactions.subscribe(data => {
        this.transaction =  data.filter((item) => {
           return item.tx_id === txn_id;
        });
        this.transaction = this.transaction[0];
     });
     this.transactionOk = true;
  }
```

In the **confirm.route** component class, there is a condition. If the condition is true, it redirects to the **success.route**. 
That works fine..

Now, within the **success.route**, I have a routerLink to navigate to the **status.route**. This works fine too.

Then in the status.route I have a template form.

The problem comes, when I go **from** the **confirm.route**, it redirects me to the **success.route** as expected. When I click to go the **status.route**, it works just fine.

However, if I submit the form in the **status.route**, it redirects me to the **success.route**.

In the **status.route**, there's no condition to redirect.

note: I do use ngOnDestroy on both success and confirm class.
      If I reload the page on **success.route** or **status.route**, it works just fine.

So why is the conditional in **`confirm.route`** still working while I am in the **`status.route`**? Is this due to ngrx?

Comment: can you send the html?

Comment: which of the html? this doesn't seem to have anything to do the view, does it?

Comment: what if your html submit is an anchor tag and by clicking that it is changing the page depending on `href` property

Comment: no, it's an html button. ``` <button [disabled]="!statusForm.valid" type="submit" class="btn  btn-info w-100 btn-lg">Check Transaction</button>```

Comment: Are you failing to unsubscribe from your ngrx select? It doesn't look like you are holding onto the subscription for later unsubscribing.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel I am doing so with ```ngOnDestroy() { this.subscription.unsunscribe()}```. Do I need to be doing more?

Comment: You have multiple subscriptions going on, so yeah

Comment: Thank you @DanielWStrimpel. That was it.